# Oracle 64-bit server 2008 Installation

Tags: oracle10g

I want to install oracle on 64-bit version, 2008 server.

Can anybody guide me which software i should install? I want both Oracle client and server.

Answer (score 0):

please specify what do you want to install. Is it database, application server or something else?

If you want to install database, I would suggest you to check compatibility matrix for database version you plan to install. Only "free" database form Oracle is XE and it only exists in 32 bit version for windows platform.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/downloads/index.html

regards

Comment: Actually i want to install oracle 10g R2 database.

Comment: in that case I would give a shoot to this:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204-winx64-vista-win2k8-082253.html

but take it with reserve, because I'm not an Oracle expert. :)